# Isotope filtering in ruby on rails usinf postgresql

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jquery-isotope

I am making a project in Ruby on rails and using PostgreSQL as DB. Now I want Isotope filter to work on it using **jQuery**.

On using **isotope filtering**, for multiple selection like.It should retrieve the matching criteria from DB and dynamically new tags should be generated on refreshing the page based on entries in database row count.

So the number of row count from database will display no of thumbnails on webpage everytime.The main concern over here is generating HTML tags dynamically.

Can anyone help?

```
<h1>Isotope - combination filters</h1>
```

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JEojz 
If possible help me with modifications on the codepen link.
Thanks

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. What is your expected behaviour and what is the actual behaviour of your source code?

Comment: <1/2>I am sorry for that. Actually, i don't have any code ready for it...just the idea...i am building web app using ROR. That uses db to retrieve info on user query. i want that result to be shown in form of isotope filter as i mentioned the link above.
For e.g. 

<div class="grid">
  <div class="color-shape small round red"></div>
  ...
</div>

should be dynamically generated as.....

Comment: <2/2>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="mum jan red"></div>
  <div class="mum feb blue"></div>
 ....
</div>
Here all the tags will be generated from the db automatically, but on using filter, only one tag will get activated..like where div class is "mum, jan and red."